# How to push data on the key itself when instantiating a new object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

On implementing a symbol search box with two options (DB Search and Web Api Search). While I am typing the symbol (ex: AAPL - aple stock) in the search box the `fetch()` request is sent each time over the network. And then the result is saved in Database. Each time when I am instantiating a `new Stock()` object I am pushing the result to Object data key. Of cause it does not work

```
const stock = new Stock({ //const {Stock} = require('../models/Stock')
      symbol: curValue,// req.params.symbol
      data: webApiData.map(function (item) {
        this.data.push(item)
      })
    })
```

As a solution a push is outside of the `new Stock({})`

```
 webApiData.map(item => {
      stock.data.push(item)
    })
```

**Here is the full working code:**

```
(async function creatStock() {
  try {
    const webApiData = await fetchWebApi(urlCompact)
    const stock = new Stock({ //const {Stock} = require('../models/Stock')
      symbol: curValue// req.params.symbol
      // data: webApiData.map(function (item) {
      //   this.data.push(item)
      // })
    })

    webApiData.map(item => {
      stock.data.push(item)
    })

    const query = { symbol: `${curValue}` }
    const update = { $addToSet: { data: stock.data } }
    const options = { upsert: true, new: true }

    const stockResult = await Stock.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options)
    console.log('Saved the symbol web TO db', stockResult.symbol)
    return res.send(webApiData)

  } catch (ex) {
    console.log(`creatStock error: ${ex.errors}`)
  }
})()
```

**Here is the Schema of the DB**

```
const ChildSchemaData = new mongoose.Schema({
  "_id": false,
  date: { type: mongoose.Types.Decimal128 },
  open: { type: mongoose.Types.Decimal128 },
  high: { type: mongoose.Types.Decimal128 },
  low: { type: mongoose.Types.Decimal128 },
  close: { type: mongoose.Types.Decimal128 },
  volume: { type: mongoose.Types.Decimal128 }
})

const ParentSchemaSymbol = new mongoose.Schema({
  "_id": false,
  symbol: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    minlength: 1,
    uppercase: true,
    required: 'Please enter a valid symbol, min 1 character'
  },
  // Array of subdocuments
  data: [ChildSchemaData],
  slug: String

})
```

Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Why not just `data: webApiData`? There doesn't look to be any need for `.map` at all

Comment: `webApiData` is the result of the `fetch()` array of objects that I stiil have to loop througth and push in to  key `data:`. Or I do not understand what you meant ?

Comment: Why do you need to loop? Why can't you just define the `.data` property as the plain array response `webApiData`?

Comment: I just added the Schema to the question.

Comment: I am fetching the data to draw a chart that contains a lot of data points that I have to loop through

Comment: I just tested it looks good! Thank you!